# Compile PHP 7 on Windows

Tags: php, windows, compilation, php-7

In the official [Build your own PHP on Windows](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild) manual, information about release `configure` command is [outdated](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/release) for the PHP 7. Please, can someone tell me, how exactly I must write this command to get same PHP compared to official NTS precompiled version?

I tried `configure --enable-snapshot-build --enable-debug-pack --disable-zts --with-pdo-oci=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared --with-oci8=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared --with-oci8-11g=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient11\sdk,shared`, but in compiled snapshot.txt I found `com_dotnet` which is not existent in official release...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer has been near — "Configure Command" parameter in `phpinfo()` contains actual `configure` arguments used in compilation.

Comment: I still get a '-h win32\' '-h' notrecognized as internal or external command.